# Adding functionality to a firemonkey Treeviewitem checkbox // Limit on Firemonkey style Events?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I use the following method to add functionality to the checkbox of my Treeviewitem.

```
function TForm.CreateTVObj:TTreeviewItem;
var
  MyCheckbox:TCheckbox;
begin
  try
    result:=TTreeviewItem.create(nil);
    result.Parent:=Treeview;

    result.StyleLookup:='treeviewitemstyle';

    MyCheckbox:= result.FindStyleResource('check') as TCheckbox;
    //the functionality:
    MyCheckbox.OnChange:= CheckBoxChange;

  except
    on e:exception do begin
      ShowMessage('Error'+chr(13)+chr(13)+e.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

### Now i have the following problem:

it works for a limited number of items.
If i add to much items, **the checkboxchange only fires for the first 9-12 items**.

Is there a Limit?
If i start checking them from the top only the first 12 work.
If I click on the last item first, the first 3 also don't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably find that the check box's OnChange event is hooked into internally by the tree view.

You need to hook into the treeview's OnCheckChange instead. If you're using XE2 the Sender will be the ListBoxItem which has been changed.

In early versions of XE3 it will be the TreeView itself and you'll need to find some other way to find which item was changed (i.e. recurse the tree elements and compare their state to your original data).

QC is showing that this has been fixed in a recent update but I haven't have a chance to test it http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=109138

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).